# Can't start process when starting erlag node

Tags: erlang

I was trying to start a supervisor and a gen_server process while one node is created from the command-line, I use the following command to start the node:

```
erl -name vm01@192.168.146.129 -s ets_sup start vm02@192.168.146.129 calc
```

However, I found the process is `undefined` when I use `whereis` to check the process on the newly created node. I got no problems running ets_sup and ets_srv on the node shell directly, but starting the node from command line doesn't work. I want to know why this happening?

ets_sup.erl:

```
-module(ets_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-export([start/1, start_link/1, init/1]).

start([A, B]) ->
        start_link([A, B]).


start_link([A, B]) ->
        supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [A, B]).

init([A, B]) ->
        {ok, {{one_for_all, 0, 1},
                [{ets_srv, {ets_srv, start_link, [A, B]}, permanent, 5000, worker, [ets_srv]}]}}.
```

ets_srv.erl:

```
-module(ets_srv).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-compile(export_all).

-record(state, {a, b}).

start_link(A,B) ->
        gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [A, B], []).

init([A, B]) ->
        {ok, #state{a = A, b = B}}.

check_sys() ->
        gen_server:call(?MODULE, check_sys).

handle_call(check_sys, _From, #state{a = A, b = B} = State) ->
        {reply, {A, B}, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State) -> {noreply, State}.

handle_cast(_Req, State) -> {noreply, State}.

code_change(_Ol, State, _Ex) -> {ok, State}.

terminate(_R, _S) -> ok.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that you really start the function `ets_sup:start/1` with your parameter list. You can verify it by adding an `io:format(...)` before the `ets_sup:start_link/1`.

but the process who executes the function `ets_sup:start/1` is an early one who dies very soon with reason `shutdown`, and as your supervisor is linked to it, it dies too, with all its children.

You have to call this function from a process that will not die (usually, it is the role of the application manager). For example, do:

```
start([A, B]) ->
    % spawn a new process
    spawn(fun () -> 
               start_link([A, B]),
               % add a loop to keep it alive
               loop()
               end).


loop() ->
    receive
        stop -> ok;
        _ -> loop()
    end.
```

**Edit, but not an answer**

I have modified your code:

- add `process_flag(trap_exit, true),` in the init server, in order to catch an exit message,
- add `io:format("server terminate with reason ~p, process ~p~n",[_R,self()]),` in the server terminate function in order to print an exit reason eventually sent by the supervisor *(Note: if an exit message is sent by another process, handle_info will be triggered).*
- add `ets_srv:check_sys()` in the supervisor, just after the start of the server in order to check if it did star correctly.

Here is the modified code.

```
-module(ets_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-export([start/1, start_link/1, init/1]).

start([A, B]) ->
    start_link([A, B]).


start_link([A, B]) ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [A, B]),
    ets_srv:check_sys().

init([A, B]) ->
    {ok, {{one_for_all, 0, 1},
            [{ets_srv, {ets_srv, start_link, [A, B]}, permanent, 5000, worker, [ets_srv]}]}}.

-module(ets_srv).
-behaviour(gen_server).
-compile(export_all).

-record(state, {a, b}).

start_link(A,B) ->
    gen_server:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [A, B], []).

init([A, B]) ->
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    {ok, #state{a = A, b = B}}.

check_sys() ->
    gen_server:call(?MODULE, check_sys).

handle_call(check_sys, _From, #state{a = A, b = B} = State) ->
    io:format("check_sys state ~p, process ~p~n",[State,self()]),
    {reply, {A, B}, State}.

handle_info(_Info, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

handle_cast(_Req, State) ->
    {noreply, State}.

code_change(_Ol, State, _Ex) ->
    {ok, State}.

terminate(_R, _S) ->
    io:format("server terminate with reason ~p, process ~p~n",[_R,self()]),
    ok.
```

Running this version shows that the supervisor starts the server correctly, and then it sends a shutdown message to it. This does not occurs if the supervisor is started in the shell.

```
C:\src>erl -s ets_sup start vm02@192.168.146.129 calc
check_sys state {state,'vm02@192.168.146.129',calc}, process <0.56.0>
server terminate with reason shutdown, process <0.56.0>
Eshell V8.2  (abort with ^G)
1> whereis(ets_srv).
undefined
2> ets_sup:start(['vm02@192.168.146.129',calc]).
check_sys state {state,'vm02@192.168.146.129',calc}, process <0.61.0>
{'vm02@192.168.146.129',calc}
3> whereis(ets_srv).
<0.61.0>
4> ets_srv:check_sys().
check_sys state {state,'vm02@192.168.146.129',calc}, process <0.61.0>
{'vm02@192.168.146.129',calc}
5> exit(whereis(ets_srv),shutdown).
true
6> whereis(ets_srv).
<0.61.0>
7> exit(whereis(ets_srv),kill).
** exception exit: shutdown
8> whereis(ets_srv).
undefined
9>
```

I have verified that if you start an ordinary process (not a supervisor) the same way, using `spawn_link`, it doesn't receive any exit message.

```
-module (st).

-compile([export_all]).

start(Arg) ->
    do_start(Arg).

do_start(Arg) ->
    io:format("spawn from ~p~n",[self()]),
    register(?MODULE,spawn_link(fun () -> init(Arg) end)).

init(Arg) ->
    io:format("init with ~p in ~p~n",[Arg,self()]),
    process_flag(trap_exit, true),
    Pid = self(),
    spawn(fun() -> monitor(process,Pid), receive M -> io:format("loop received ~p~n",[M]) end end),
    loop(Arg).

loop(Arg) ->
    receive
        state ->
            io:format("state is ~p~n",[Arg]),
            loop(Arg);
        stop ->
            io:format("stopping~n");
        _ ->
            loop(Arg)
    end.
```

The execution gives:

```
C:\src>erl -s st start vm02@192.168.146.129 calc
spawn from <0.3.0>
init with ['vm02@192.168.146.129',calc] in <0.55.0>
Eshell V8.2  (abort with ^G)
1> whereis(st).
<0.55.0>
2> exit(whereis(st),shutdown).
true
3> whereis(st).
<0.55.0>
4> st ! state.
state is ['vm02@192.168.146.129',calc]
state
5> st ! stop.
stopping
loop received {'DOWN',#Ref<0.0.4.66>,process,<0.55.0>,normal}
stop
6> whereis(st).
undefined
7>
```

**Edit, another way to "detach" the supervisor**

All the tests I have done show that the supervisor receives a shutdown message. I don't know why, usually I use the application mechanism to start a supervision tree, and I never met this situation.

I propose you to unlink the supervisor from its parent, so it will not receive a shutdown message:

```
-module(ets_sup).
-behaviour(supervisor).
-export([start/1, start_link/1, init/1]).

start([A, B]) ->
    start_link([A, B]).


start_link([A, B]) ->
    supervisor:start_link({local, ?MODULE}, ?MODULE, [A, B]),
    ets_srv:check_sys().

init([A, B]) ->
    {links,[Parent]} = process_info(self(),links),
    unlink(Parent),
    {ok, {{one_for_all, 0, 1},
            [{ets_srv, {ets_srv, start_link, [A, B]}, permanent, 5000, worker, [ets_srv]}]}}.
```

An now it works:

```
C:\src>erl -s ets_sup start vm02@192.168.146.129 calc
check_sys state {state,'vm02@192.168.146.129',calc}, process <0.56.0>
Eshell V8.2  (abort with ^G)
1> ets_srv:check_sys().
check_sys state {state,'vm02@192.168.146.129',calc}, process <0.56.0>
{'vm02@192.168.146.129',calc}
2>
```